# How do I commit suicide?

Tags: overwatch

I was recently playing on a KOTH map, Illios, and for some reason, on the second round, I ended up spawning in the enemy team's ship.

I think it's most likely a bug that got me there, but here's the rest of the problem.  When I tried to leave the enemy team's ship (spawn point), the yellow barrier prevented me from leaving.

The enemy team refused to kill me, finding it somewhat amusing I was in their spawn and thus not only could I not damage them, I could not escape at all, making me their pet.

In any case, I tried changing heroes to return the menu but I got the message "You must be in a spawn room to change heroes.", despite me being in a spawn room, albeit the enemies.

Is there a suicide command that I can bind a key to should I be unable to get out of a spot or be glitched out, just like in this case?

Comment: I have no idea, but that sounds funny. And I feel it was wrong for them to keep you trapped. Anyway, did you have any weapons which can cause splash damage?

Comment: Please try to remember what you were you doing before you spawned in the enemy ship

Comment: @Auro I was unfortunately playing as D.va so I had no real way of doing self-damage to myself.

Comment: @jojo as D.Va then, keep shooting them to build ultimate... then set off your ultimate in their spawn when you see 2 or 3 respawn. That will make them rethink killing you!

Comment: @DoktorJ You can't deal damage to enemies inside their spawn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having looked through pretty much all options and controls in the game, I have not ever seen an option to commit suicide. So unless you are playing a hero who has splash damage, you cannot kill yourself. If you are not playing a hero with splash damage, your best bet is just to quit the match so your team can get someone able to do stuff.

You may also want to report the issue to Blizzard so they can maybe figure out what is wrong and fix the bug.

Comment: I wonder if being in a spawn, albeit in the enemy spawn, you could even damage yourself?

Comment: You definitely can't damage yourself within your own spawn zone (the yellow barriers), and KOTH maps set the entire ship as your spawn zone. If it doesn't care about the team and just nullifies damage in that zone, then splash wouldn't have helped either..

Answer (score 3):

If you are playing any character with explosives (<strike>Junkrat</strike>, Pharah, Zarya, Soldier 76), you can aim your explosives at your own feet to blow yourself up. In normal circumstances, you could also jump off a cliff or into a hole to kill yourself (obviously not possible in your scenario).

Other than that there is no way to kill yourself. You would either have to wait until the round is over, or until you get disconnected/quit the game.

You may want to post this bug on the forums as well, in case it's something that Blizzard can fix.

---

NOTE: As of the patch on March 21, 2017, Junkrat can no longer damage himself with his own bombs.

Comment: Junkrat can still blow himself up with his Rip-Tire.It'll take a while to charge, and it's a "waste" of an ult, but he can still technically get out.